# Add property to Identity in MVC 5, using Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm using MVC 5 and EF 6 (Datafirst),using msssql management studio.

I created a new mvc project, which came up with built database (AspNetUsers etc)

I also created a new table called UserDetails, which it purpose to contain more details about the user by it's Id (so I created a link between AspNetUsers id column to UserDetails UserId column)

therefore I added the following code

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {

        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here 
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName",  FirstName.ToString()));

        return userIdentity;
    }
    //Extended Propeties
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

}
```

But of course it's not working, I looked over the internet for over 4 hours now, can someone please guide me ? I'm new to MVC, everything seems to be complicated much.
I also have the following static method :

```
    public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static string GetFirstName(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("FirstName");
        // Test for null to avoid issues during local testing
        return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

in order to get it in the view and display it..
my goal is to display data from another table (UserDetails) in the view based on connection of 1-1 from AspNetUsers (UserDetails.UserId == AspNetUsers.Id)

Comment: If you add property in ApplicationUser class it should work properly ... Whats the problem ?? have you updated your database after adding that property ?? ....

Comment: @DaniyalAwan "The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database" when I try to login, it's because it tries to fetch firstname but it doesn't exist in AspNetUsers, it's in UserDetails..

Comment: No, You have created firstName in applicationUser, not in UserDetails so how can it be in UserDetails .. I think the problem is that you have created firstname but didnt updated the database ... Use migrations to update the database

Comment: @DaniyalAwan I have 2 tables,AspNetUsers and UserDetails, I did datbase first, now I have key in both of them, i connected those keys. I want to access fields in UserDetails from the User.Identity, how can i do that? what I'm suppose to do? I updated the identity model to try to achieve that but no success..

Comment: Here's blog post titled 'Customizing profile information in ASP.NET Identity in VS 2013 templates' https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates/ It looks very useful for this purpose.

Comment: @jyrkim I saw that before.. didn't help much :/

Comment: Still need help guys :/

Comment: follow one of the tutorials, in my experience, I have used code first with asp.net application user. after you add the property you can follow the suggestion and run the commands 'enable-migrations' then 'add-migration add-first-name' the 'update-database'. otherwise you will want to look for a tutorial for database first with identity user.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is extend the IdentityUser class, then add your custom properties like FirstName etc.. then since you are using EntityFramework Database first you need to enable the migrations with this command in your package manager console `enable-migrations`, then add an initial migration like `add-migration initialMigration`, after that update the database using migrations with this command `update-database`, the AspNetUsers table in your database will now have the new columns you added. Use migration to keep your database in sync with your models

Answer (score 0):

if there is correct connection between both table you can use [Eagerly Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) to get the details of one entity from another.